# Impact of SQL Server 2012 cu installation on SP 2013 on premise

Tags: sharepoint-server, project-server, cumulative-update, sql-server-2012

I have to install the KB4019090 on my SQL Server 2012.

My SharePoint 2013 farm with MS Project 2013 depends of it.

What are the best practice to follow to make sure my farm will be up and running after the update?

Thanks a lot !

Regards,

Comment: KB4019090 deals with analysis services component of sql server. Do you have that functionality required in your application? As far as I know, there is no direct linkage/dependency b/ween KB4019090 and  MS Project 2013 . But as a general practice you can install the same , KB4019090 in your dev.env and  test any features of MS PROJECT 2013 are getting affected or not. If not , you can confidently install the KB4019090 on your PROD. Env.

Comment: to be honest, I'm not managing the app themselves, only the core part of Project as I don't know this product :( I was more looking for a procedure/best practice procedure with steps to follow before the DBA deploys this update on the SQL server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have installed tons of SQL-Server Updates on lots of SharePoint farms. SharePoint never got broken.

But if you heavily rely on that environment, you should have a testing-environment that matches prod environment as close as possible. You can install updates there and check if everything works as expected. Checklists are very helpful to standardize this process. You should also get your application-owners involved to help you building those checklists!

I would recommend to install Cumulative Update 10 for SQL-Server 2012 ServicePack 3 ([KB4025925](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4025925/cumulative-update-10-for-sql-server-2012-sp3)) instead of KB4019090. The hotfix is contained in the CU. CUs are tested way more intensive by Microsoft than a hotfix.

The process of installing the update is very straightforward:

- Make sure you have a working full backup!
- Shut down your SharePoint-Server. This makes sure every database-connection is closed. Just stopping IIS will still keep lots of connections open.
- Install the Update on SQL-Server. If necessary, restart the Server
- Make sure SQL Server works as expected (e.g. by connecting via SQL Server Management Studio)
- Start SharePoint and check if everything works as expected.

Comment: thanks for your input. Should I switch off all of them (WFE + Apps + OWA ) ? Thanks a lot :)

Comment: WFE + App: Yes. OWA does not open any database connection, so it can stay online during the patching process.

Comment: I would also take the full backup of databases before applying patches. and full backup after updates.